Possible inconsistency/mistake in Stephen King's Fairy Tale?
In Stephen King's Fairy Tale (2022), the protagonist, Charlie Reade, is in high school around 2013 (the year is explicitly mentioned). One of his teachers asks him about Alton Sterling's killing, which took place in 2016 (in the future, from the protagonist's perspective).
Is this an inconsistency/mistake in the writing, or on my side, or something else?

High school covers four years. Why is this an inconsistency?

Does the novel happen over weeks or years?  If enough years pass after 2013 there is no problem with talking about Alton Sterling's 2016 death.  If not enough time passes there is a problem.  2016 is between a little over 2 years to almost 4 years after 2013.  HIgh school usually lasts for about 3.75
years.  The question says the protagonist is in high school, this  https://stephenking.com/works/novel/fairy-tale.htmlsays he is 17.  17 is between a little more than 2 years to almost 4 years after someone usually enters high school.  Thus the time span in the story is important.

I'm honestly not sure the span between the citation of 2013 and the highschool incident. I guess it could be four years (2013 being the year his mother dies, and then him being in highschool several years later). Just seemed weird to me, timing-wise.

Relevant quotes from the hardback edition of Fairytale:

The Little Rumple River runs through the north end of Sentry’s Rest (known to the locals as Sentry), and until 1996, the year I was born, it was spanned by a wooden bridge.

(Chapter 1, section 2)

One Saturday in November of 2003… my mother told us she was going to walk down to the Zippy and get us fried chicken for dinner

(Chapter 1, section 3)
The main part of the story takes place in the fall of 2013, when Charlie Reade is 17 (Chapter 1, Section 10, last line starts in April 2013).

"Then perhaps you’d give us your considered opinion concerning the blue-on-black shootings of Philando Castile and Alton Sterling."

(Chapter 11, section 5, question asked by a teacher in class - in the story, this is the autumn term of school, some time after September 2013, there are enough events in the story that imply time is running as normal at that point).
In Chapter 32, Section 3, it is revealed that Charlie's main adventure took place from October 2013 to February 2014 (he was reported "missing" during that time). So although time is quite fluid in places, there are firm dates for some parts of the story.
So, yes, on the face of it, if you assume the story is set in our world with our timeline, the mention of the 2016 Alton shooting is apparently out of sync. But, the story is narrated by Charlie himself, and, at that point, school is very much not his main focus, so it could be considered a false memory or unreliable narrator. It’s an appropriate topic to cover because some of the main themes later in the book could reflect it ( Charlie is later threatened and mistreated by creatures in a position of official authority).

Good answer, thanks. Interesting addendum: in the final chapter, it mentions Charles "Charlie" Reade disappeared in October of 2013 (referring to him going in the shed and into the other world). So it really is an inconsistency.
